# squeeze function in numpy running out of memory

Tags: python, maps, contour

I try to make a climatic map in python which I am not used to use but want to try if it is more handy than plotting in R. I use the example by
http://joehamman.com/2013/10/12/plotting-netCDF-data-with-Python/ with my data.

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np

myfil = "xxxxx"
fh = Dataset(myfil, mode='r')
lons = fh.variables['lon'][:]
lats = fh.variables['lat'][:]
tmean = fh.variables['Tmean_ANN'][:1]

from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Get some parameters for the Stereographic Projection

lon0 = lons.mean()
lats0 = lats.mean()



m = Basemap(width=5000000,height=3500000,
            resolution='l',projection='stere',
            lat_ts=60,lat_0=lats0,lon_0=lon0)

lon, lat = np.meshgrid(lons, lats, sparse=True)
xi, yi = m(lon, lat)

# Plot Data

print(xi.shape)
print(yi.shape)
print(tmean.shape)
```

results

```
(1, 1142761)
(1142761, 1)
(1, 1069, 1069)
```

Trying to run this line

```
cs = m.contour(xi,yi, np.squeeze(tmean))
```

I got the error

```
cs = m.contour(xi,yi, np.squeeze(tmean))
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-37-8be9f03a0e45>", line 1, in <module>
    cs = m.contour(xi,yi, np.squeeze(tmean))

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\basemap\__init__.py", line 546, in with_transform
    return plotfunc(self,x,y,data,*args,**kwargs)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\basemap\__init__.py", line 3566, in contour
    np.logical_or(np.greater(x,self.xmax+epsx),np.greater(y,self.ymax+epsy))

MemoryError
```

Any help why do I got this. My hypothesis is that the dimension of `xi`  and `yi` is not compatible with `tmean` thus I got the error. The `np.sqeeze` function works with `tmean` data outside the `m.contour` function But I could not solve that for a while.

Comment: What is the output of `print(xi.shape)`, `print(yi.shape)` and `print(tmean.shape)`?

Comment: I uppdated the question with the info you pointed out

Comment: The size of the arrays is strange. What are the dimensions of original lons and lats? Please add `np.shape(lons)` and `np.shape(lats)`.

Comment: `1142761 == 1069 * 1069`

Comment: If the data is on regular grid, I suggest reshaping longitude and latitude from vector form i.e. dimensions (1142761,1) or (1,1142761) to matrix or 2D form i.e. dimensions (1069,1069). Might be that method contour upon receiving vectors as coordinates is trying to make meshgrid from those vectors i.e. matrices with dimensions (1142761,1142761), which are definitely too large.